# MVC: Upload image in partial view, routing problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to upload images via a form which sits in partial view using MVC.

View Code:

```
<form action="/Item/ImageUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <%= Html.TextBox("ItemId",Model.ItemId) %>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file"  />
   <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Action Code:

```
public void ImageUpload(string ItemId, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
// upload image
// Add Image record to database
// Associate Image record to Item record
//Go back to existing view where the partial view sits
RedirectToAction("Details/"+ItemId);
}
```

The Image is uploaded successful

All the data manipulation are working as expected

However instead of redirect to view "Item/Details/id", page went to "/Item/ImageUpload"

I tried several different way of doing this including using jsonResultAction, but all failed in this same result.

where did i do wrong, any ideas? thanks in advance

**Edit:**

I just realized all the routing which are render by the code is not working.

for example:  `[ <%= Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") %> ]`
instead of rendering `<a href="/Account/LogOff">Home</a>` it renders `<a href="">Home</a>`

however all the routings which were hard coded are all working.

Where did i break it?? It troubles that I cant event restore it.

Code for Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            //routes.MapRoute(
            //   "ImageResize",
            //   "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{value}",
            //   new { controller = "Image", action = "ShowImage", id = "", value = "" }); 

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}/",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );


        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `return RedirectToAction("Deati....`

If you already have the keyword `return` there then add that to your question and I'll remove this answer

**EDIT**

In that case I'd write a route which allows you to then say something like `return RedirectToRoute("name", model);`

**EDIT 2**

All I can offer at this point I think is from the account controller that's auto generated.

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{

    FormsAuth.SignOut();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Looking at the code you have presented I see `public void ImageUpload` rather than `public ActionResult ImageUpload`.

Comment: I have just tried again by returning ActionResult, but page still went to "Item/ImageUpload" with "No route in the route table matches the supplied values" Error, since i did not create that view in my project at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectToAction("Details/"+ItemId);
```

This should Be

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new {Id = ItemId});
```

You dont just add stuff to the RedirectToAction like that. 
It uses reflection to pick up the Parameters for the method that you are redirecting to.